# Proving that $E$ is Lebesgue-measurable $\iff E\cap (n,n+1)$ is Lebesgue-Measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $I_{n}=(n,n+1]$ defined for $n\in\Bbb{Z}.$ I need to prove a subset $E\subset\Bbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-measurable $\iff E\cap I_{n}$ is Lebesgue measurable.

I denote $l^{*}$ as the Lebesgue outer measure. By definition, a set $E$ is $l^{*}-$measurable if $$l^{*}(A)=l^{*}(A\cap E)+l^{*}(A\,\backslash\, E)\;\forall \, A\subset\Bbb{R}.$$

At the beginning of the question, it asks me to prove that if $E$ is contained in a finite union of $I_{n}$, so $l^{*}(E)<\infty,$ which was pretty simple.

Next, asks me to build a Lebesgue-Measurable set $E$ such that $l^{*}(E)<\infty$ and $l^{*}(E\cap I_{n})>0\forall n\in\Bbb{Z}.$ I did it like follows:

For each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, define $a_{n}=n+\frac{1}{2}$ (the mid term in $I_{n})$. Now, define 
$$r_{n}= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2^n} \quad\textrm{if}\quad n>0, \\
-\frac{1}{2^n}\quad\textrm{if}\quad n<0 ,\\
\frac{1}{2}\quad\textrm{if}\quad n=0.
\end{cases}$$
The $r_{n}$ will be the radius of subintervals of $I_{n}$ centered in $a_{n}.$ Finally, define $E_{n}=(a_{n}-\frac{r_{n}}{2},a_{n}+\frac{r_{n}}{2})$ and $E=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}E_{n}.$ By construction, $E_{n}\subset I_{n},$ so

$$l^{*}(E\cap I_{n})=l^{*}(E_{n})=r_{n}>0\; \forall\, n\in\Bbb{Z}.$$

Together, we have

$$l^{*}(E)=l^{*}\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}E_{n}\right)\leq\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}l^{*}(E_{n})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}l^{*}(E_{n})+\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}l^{*}(E_{n})+l^{*}(E_{0})=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}r_{n}+\frac{1}{2}=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2}=4+\frac{1}{2}<\infty\implies l^{*}(E)<\infty. $$

I have two questions:

**1)** Is my construct of $E$ consistent? If not, what need I to change?

**2)** Can I use some of these facts to prove the sufficient and necessarilly conditions for $l^{*}-$measurable ? How to approach this question? I really don't know.

Comment: $l^{*}(A)=l^{*}(A\cap E)+l^{*}(A\,\backslash\, E)\;\forall \, A\subset\Bbb R$ is the definition of Lebesgue measurability, not "$l^*$-measurable", which is not a real term since $l^*$ is defined on every set. Also, the middle formula for $r_n$ should be $1/2^{-n}$, not $-1/2*n$, which makes no sense for a radius. You could express the whole thing as $r_n = 1/2^{|n|}$ for all $n$ (note that $E_0 \subset (0,1)$ even when $r_0 = 1$). But these are trivial corrections. You still need to show your constructed $E$ is Lebesgue measurable (hint: its a union of intervals).

Comment: As for (2), not the second exercise. It is just to build up your acquaintance with measurable sets. The first exercise where $E$ is contained in a finite union is useful for the larger goal.